# how to recover the variable clicked in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

a just need to recover (in 'myfunction') my variable 'name' on my row when i click on my button

**this my index page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Pays</th>
    <th>Ville</th>
    <th>button</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <td value="{{x.Name}}">{{ x.Name | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.City }}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script src="Ctrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      console.log($scope.myData);
      $scope.myfunction = function(){


      }
  });
});
```

and this is my file php

```
{ "records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, {"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"}, {"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"}, {"Name":"Berglunds snabbköp","City":"Luleå","Country":"Sweden"}, {"Name":"Blauer See Delikatessen","City":"Mannheim","Country":"Germany"}, {"Name":"Blondel père et fils","City":"Strasbourg","Country":"France"}, {"Name":"Bólido Comidas preparadas","City":"Madrid","Country":"Spain"}, {"Name":"Bon app'","City":"Marseille","Country":"France"}, {"Name":"Bottom-Dollar Marketse","City":"Tsawassen","Country":"Canada"}, {"Name":"Cactus Comidas para llevar","City":"Buenos Aires","Country":"Argentina"}, {"Name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, {"Name":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"}, {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"} ] }
```

thanks in advance for your reponse,

Comment: did you try passing `x.Name` in `myFunction()`  like `myFunction(x.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tried this easy thing in your way but did not get any data inside the function on controller because of a typo :)

You did a very silly mistake while calling the function from inside HTML. You typed it as `myFunction()` Where as the calling name should be `myfunction()` as per your controller's code.

So, the following thing works perfectly!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Pays</th>
    <th>Ville</th>
    <th>button</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <td value="{{ x.Name }}">{{ x.Name | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.City }}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="myfunction(x.Name)">Click me!</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script src="Ctrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

With `Ctrl.js` like following ...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      console.log($scope.myData);
      $scope.myfunction = function(Name){
            console.log(Name);
      }
  });
});
```

> Javascript is Case Sensitive!